# Constraints error <Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint>

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is my `UICollectionViewCell` image...

[image]

I am added the autolayout constraints to this cell...but it gives me lots of breaking constraints error....Then I decided to go step by step to resolve the braking constraints error.so I just give the constraints to **UIImageView and title label**, and the console log is....

```
 (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x158cec50 H:[UIImageView:0x158de490(100)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1582bd30 H:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x158de490]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x158db340 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1582bd90 H:[UILabel:0x158de540'Rhythm | Responsive Multi...']-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x158db340 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1582b200 H:[UIImageView:0x158de490]-(7)-[UILabel:0x158de540'Rhythm | Responsive Multi...']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15800a00 H:[UIView:0x158db340]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x158cea10 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15800a60 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x158db340]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x158cea10 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x147cfe50 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x158cea10(50)]>"
 )

 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
 <NSLayoutConstraint:0x158cec50 H:[UIImageView:0x158de490(100)]>
```

Here is my **UIImageView constraints  and my title label** constraint 
  [image]  [image]

I want my UIImageview width is 100..so when I just added above constraints for image...its fine but as soon as I added leading constraint of label...it causes problem...and I want label width dynamic

SO, how can I resolve this errors...

**EDIT**
My view hierarchy

```
-Cell
   - View 
       - Image  
       - Title
```

**SOLVED**
   This 2 lines solved the issue....

```
 cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
 cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin
```

**CURIOUS ABOUT**
But I want to know why is it so....because in some project with same layout and same constraints, its working fine and in some its not...**WHY???**

Comment: Your current constraint looks fine.. make sure you have not given any constraint to any other subview

Comment: @SidShah I thought the same thing and i am pretty sure that my constraints are right but i don't know why this error comes

Comment: do in one demo. I have set the constraint as your.. no error

Comment: @SidShah thanx....but why is it not working for me???

Comment: did u clear al the constraints first

Comment: yes..i did that....but i just not apply width constraint for my title label as it is dynamic..

Comment: doesn't it still work

Comment: no buddy...not at all

Comment: @Bhavin There is a problem in your constraints on the Label. You can't have constraints with Leading-Trailing and Width all together. When you set Leading-Trailing it supposed to scale the width, in this case you can't fix the width. Remove Width constaint it should work, this might be conflicting, check similar constraint you might have set.

Comment: @iphonic  i had no constraint `width` in label...its with imageview which i want to be to set 100....as cell width is not fixed.is set as per devices and want extra space for label

Comment: I can see a Width constraint and Leading-Trailing in the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/kMEHN.png. Its all related, a wrong constraint may break other constraint too.

Comment: @iphonic brother...if i dont set width to image...i had flexible width of image...which obviously i dont want...as i want flexible width for label

Comment: @Bhavin Then remove trailing constraint from the UIImageView?

Comment: @iphonic If i remove trailing constraint from imageview...then what about leading space constraint of label

Comment: @Bhavin You can add that with contentView not the UIImageView, or you can have a UIImageView Container and do that.

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

place the constraints as below screen shots

[image]

[image]

[image]